# How to sort an XML file by date in XLST

Tags: xslt

I am trying to sort by date and get an error message about the stylesheet can't be loaded

I found an answer on how others have suggested but it doesn't work for me

Here is where it is supposed to sort.  The commented out line is where the sort should occur

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

 <xsl:template name="hoo" match="/">
  <html>
   <head>
    <title>Registered Festival Organisers and Festivals</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="userfestival.css" />
   </head>
   <body>
    <h1>Registered Festival Organisers and Festivals</h1>

    <xsl:for-each select="folktask/member">

     <xsl:if test="user/account/userlevel='3'">
      <!--<xsl:sort select="concat(substring(festival/event/datefrom,1,4),substring(festival/event/datefrom, 6,2),substring(festival/event/datefrom, 9,2))" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>-->
```

Sample node from XML

```
    <festival id="1">
     <event>
      <eventname>Oxford Folk Festival</eventname>
      <url>http://www.oxfordfolkfestival.com/</url>
      <datefrom>2010-04-07</datefrom>
      <dateto>2010-04-09</dateto>
      <location>Oxford</location>
      <eventpostcode>OX1 9BE</eventpostcode>
      <coords>
       <lat>51.735640</lat>
       <lng>-1.276136</lng>
      </coords>
     </event>
    </festival>
```

Comment: can you provide exact error message and the xml from folktask down?

Comment: @AdRock: You get an error message that the XSLT file can't be loaded. I don't know about you, but to me this looks like that nothing *within* the XSLT file can be part of the problem.

Comment: This is the error message

Error loading stylesheet: Parsing an XSLT stylesheet failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to make complicated string manipulations that turn `<datefrom>` into a number. Dates in the `yyyy-mm-dd` format sort perfectly well as text.

```
<xsl:for-each select="folktask/member[user/account/userlevel='3']">
  <xsl:sort select="festival/event/datefrom" />
  <!-- ... -->
</xsl:for-each>
```